# Reference CSV data within HTML

Tags: html, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to replicate [this D3 visualisation](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426). Unfortunately, I'm working on a company intranet which is blocking my attempt to reference the csv file used in the example.

As a work around, I included the CSV data in my html with some pre-formatted text tags. Example:

```
<pre id="csvdata">
account-account-account-account-account-account,22781
account-account-account-account-account-end,3311
account-account-account-account-account-home,906
</pre>
```

The original example D3 script references the CSV file with:

```
d3.text("visit-sequences.csv", function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});
```

I'm now trying to adapt this to use a `rawCSV` variable rather than the `"visit-sequences.csv"` but running into some trouble. Attempts below result in **object doesn't support property or method getElementByID** then **invalid argument** errors respectively.

Attempt 1:

```
var rawCSV = document.getElementByID("csvdata");
var rawCSVdata = rawCSV.html

 d3.text(rawCSVdata, function(text) {
  var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
  var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
  createVisualization(json);
});
```

Attempt 2:

```
var rawCSV = d3.select("#csvdata").text();

d3.text(rawCSV, function(text) {
var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
var json = buildHierarchy(csv);
createVisualization(json);
});
```

How can I pass this CSV data to the d3.text function??
Can I pass a variable in place of the "visit-sequences.csv" reference?

Comment: Looks like attempts #2 is close -- if `rawCSV` contains the text, then you don't need to the `d3.text(...)` wrapper. Just use `var csv = d3.csv.parse(rawCSV);` maybe?

Comment: @SteveR you're correct, OP doesn't need any XHR here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're including the CSV in the HTML as a `<pre>` you don't need any XMLHttpRequest (in this case, `d3.text()`): you're not doing any request and `rawCSV` is not an URL, the data is right there, in the `<pre>`.

So, it can be only:

```js
var rawCSV = d3.select("#csvdata").text();
var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(rawCSV);
console.log(csv)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csvdata">
account-account-account-account-account-account,22781
account-account-account-account-account-end,3311
account-account-account-account-account-home,906
</pre>
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that using a variable with [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) seems to be a cleaner option:

```js
var rawCSV = `account-account-account-account-account-account,22781
account-account-account-account-account-end,3311
account-account-account-account-account-home,906`;
var csv = d3.csv.parseRows(rawCSV);
console.log(csv)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```